# Sails.js and SQL Server database provider

Tags: sql-server, express, sails.js

As I have seen there is a very nice and solid SQL Server [connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) for Express.js

Can this be used for Sails.js as well?

Comment: Just wondering why change? SQL Server can be any server. MsSQL is Microsoft product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use Microsoft SQL Server with Sails.js! I've done it on a few projects. Really all you need to do is add it to your `config/connections.js` file:

```
sqlserver: {
        adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
        user: 'your_user',
        password: 'your_pw',
        host: 'host ip',
        database: 'your_db_name',
        // I've had to use this option in some cases
        // where the SQL Server refuses my user otherwise
        options: {
            encrypt: false
        }
},
```

Then use it the same way, by either defining it in your global config as default connection:

```
connection: 'sqlserver'
```

Or within a specific model:

```
// Define an adapter to use
adapter: 'sails-sqlserver'
```

You also might want to consider disabling some of the fields in the models like:

```
autoCreatedAt: false,
autoUpdatedAt: false,
```

And maybe enable `migrate: 'safe'` in the `configs/models.js` file.

As a side note, when I've had to do stored procedures from Node.js with a MS SQL server, I usually just fall back to using the `mssql` library directly.

Comment: Have you ever used precompiled sqlite3 with sails.js in node webkit?

Comment: I have not, unfortunately

Comment: I attempting to use it, but I wonder is it any better then the one built in sqlite in the nodewek

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with Sql server express as I added following to connections.js

```
sqlserver: {
  adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
  host: localhost'+ '\u005C' + 'sqlexpress',
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'gogators',
  database: 'users'
```

},

the host definition is wierd but came from a post on Git

my sql express has tcp/ip enabled

but I get this sails startup error:
   **    the hook 'orm' takes to long to load**

now this database i can reach from asp.net MVC with following connection string

```
   <add name="UsersContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=Users; Integrated Security=False; user=sa;password=gogators "
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **latest version of Sails.js (currently it is 1.5.8)** you will need to:

1. Install **sails-mssql** package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mssql):

```html
npm install sails-mssql --save
```

2. Configure your config/datastores.js in proper way:

```html
module.exports.datastores = {
  sqlserver: {
    adapter: 'sails-mssql',
    url: 'mssql://user:pass@host.database.windows.net:port/database',
    options: {
      encrypt: true   // use this for Azure databases 
    },
  },
};
```

Mentioned below configuration may not work due to **waterline** package used by **sails-hook-orm** as it require **url** property to be defined.

```html
module.exports.datastores = {
  sqlserver: {
    adapter: 'sails-mssql',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    host: 'name-dbserver.database.windows.net', // azure database 
    database: 'database',
    options: {
      encrypt: true   // use this for Azure databases 
    },
  }
}
```

and modify your config/models.js

```html
module.exports.models = {
  datastore: "sqlserver",
  migrate: 'safe',
};
```