# Connecting to a postgresql database with Sails 1.0.0?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I just decided to upgrade an existing Sails project to 1.0.0 and managed to get through most of the upgrade process until I tried connecting to the database. When attempting to lift this is the error I receive:

> The adapter used by the `default` datastore is not compatible with
>   the current version of Sails/Waterline.
>
> The adapter should expose a valid `adapterApiVersion`.
>
> If you're using the beta release of Sails 1.0, try:
>
> npm install --save sails-disk@beta

My `datastores.js` file contains the following:

```
module.exports.datastores = {

  // In previous versions, datastores (then called 'connections') would only be loaded
  // if a model was actually using them.  Starting with Sails 1.0, _all_ configured
  // datastores will be loaded, regardless of use.  So we'll only include datastores in
  // this file that were actually being used.  Your original `connections`  config is
  // still available as `config/connections-old.js.txt`.

   'developmentPostgres': {
    adapter: require('sails-postgresql'),
    url: process.env.postgresHost,
    user: process.env.postgresUser,
    password: process.env.postgresPassword,
    database: process.env.postgresDatabase
  }

};
```

Where all of the values are provided as environment variables. `"sails-postgresql": "^1.0.0"` is installed and saved in `package.json`

`models.js` also contains the following line: `datastore: 'developmentPostgres'`, which to my understanding means that all of my models should be using the above database by default.

Up until this point the upgrade process has been very straightforward. I assume I am just missing something simple here as well. I would appreciate any insight anyone can provide and would be happy to provide any additional information as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the project looks for a datastore labeled `default`. Changing the name to `default` in both `datastore.js` and `model.js` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my answer how to connect to MSSQL database:

[Sails.js and SQL Server database provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634721/sails-js-and-sql-server-database-provider/77286917#77286917)

It's working the same way, just use **sails-postgresql** adapter (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-postgresql)

Moving from 0.12 to 1.0 version use **@sailshq/upgrade** package (https://github.com/sailshq/upgrade-to-sails-v1). It will help you to scan application and check what should be updated.

For example renaming connection.js to datastores.js and other staff.